# Needing to move the location of a drop down box search

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a B2B website that has drop down boxes for 4 different categories that help the user narrow down their search for a specific product. Here is the code for it currently:

```
<tbody><tr class="CategorySearchResults_ItemPropertyRow">
<td class=CategorySearchResults_ItemPropertyName">Brand </td>
<td class=CategorySearchResults_ItemPropertyValue">
<select name="ItemProperty_Brand" onchange="Category_Search_Results_Content.submit();">
<option value="Any Brand">Any Brand</option>
<option value="AC DELCO">AC DELCO</option>
.... and so on for more options and three other boxes...
</tbody>
```

Right now, the drop down boxes are stacked vertically and at the bottom of my page. All I'm needing is a script that will help me re-position the drop down boxes horizontally across the top of the webpage. The position would be right underneath this table:

```
<table class="Content" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                             ...............
<tbody><tr><td><div class="BreadCrumbcategorytree_activepage"> 
<a class="BreadCrumbcategorytree_parent" href="default.aspx?Page=Home">Home</a>     
&gt;&gt; Lubricants and Fluids</div></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I have tried using a function to append the elements by class to the end of `BreadCrumbcategorytree_parent`, but I don't know if this is headed in the right direction at all or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS also effects how your elements are appearing on the page. You can use float to have them position side by side.

`select { float:left }`

This would have all your dropdowns line up (inline) until space runs out on the single line and wrap.